# Silverlight 4, MEF, Export/Import errors, Mefx doesn't want to work

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mef

Out of frustration and more than 3 days googling up this issue... i have no choice but to bother you guys with my question.

i am creating a Silverlight application. I am using MEF. When i try to run my application i get the following error.

> The invocation of the constructor on
>   type
>   'IFG.Silverlight.Client.Views.MenuView'
>   that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception. [Line:
>   25 Position: 47]

and its Inner exception is as follow...

> The composition remains unchanged. The
>   changes were rejected because of the
>   following error(s): The composition
>   produced a single composition error.
>   The root cause is provided below.
>   Review the CompositionException.Errors
>   property for more detailed
>   information.
>
> 1) No valid exports were found that
>   match the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "MenuViewModel") AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity")
>   AndAlso
>   "IFG.Silverlight.Client.ViewModel.MenuViewModel".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))',
>   invalid exports may have been
>   rejected.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'IFG.Silverlight.Client.Views.MenuView.ViewModel
>   (ContractName="MenuViewModel")' on
>   part
>   'IFG.Silverlight.Client.Views.MenuView'.
>   Element:
>   IFG.Silverlight.Client.Views.MenuView.ViewModel
>   (ContractName="MenuViewModel") --> 
>   IFG.Silverlight.Client.Views.MenuView

Ok. my code is very simple since it's a test application.

i have an Interface IRetailModel

```
namespace IFG.Silverlight.Client.Common
{
    public interface IRetailModel
    { ............
```

then i have a class that implements this interface

```
namespace IFG.Silverlight.Client.Model
{
    [Export(typeof(IRetailModel))]
    public class RetailModel : IRetailModel
    { .................
```

Then I have my ViewModel for the View

```
namespace IFG.Silverlight.Client.ViewModel
{
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    [Export(ViewModelTypes.MenuViewModel)]
    public class MenuViewModel : IFGViewModelBase
    {
 IRetailModel _model;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MenuViewModel(IRetailModel model)
        {
```

Well, i found that there is a magical tool called MefX that it's supposed to debug deep to the bone your code and tells you what's going on... I havent been able to get this to work.

I followed directions from this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2009/09/24/debug-composition-from-within-visual-studio.aspx

When i try to run it says

> Error: Unable to load one or more of
>   the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.

Then went back to Google and i found this Visual MefX (which is the same but with a GUI) and i can load the .xap but basically it gives me the same info that i get from Visual Studio. I can't find the darn [BECAUSE]...

I am really, HONESTLY AND DEEPLY, frustrated with this situation. Can anyone explain to me where am i failing to get MefX to do its job? I know the risk of dealing with these Overnight Frameworks (lack of documentation, buggy, etc etc) that MEF seems to be, but Prism is not a option to me (i feel like buying a M16 to kill a fly when i can use my finger).

Thank you

Comment: Nevermind guys... i had forgotten to add a reference to my ViewModel DLL... as simple as that... :(

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, an updated version of Visual Mefx is attached to this blog post: [How to Debug and Diagnose MEF Failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx).  It is also part of [MEFContrib](http://mefcontrib.com/), although I'm not sure if the MEFContrib version has all the changes from the version in the blog post.